# Grub doesn't install(no way till now)

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, fedora, grub

I have `windows` 10 and I installed `fedora` 24(Dual boot). I use `easyBCD` to choose OS when the PC is booted. but when I go to `federa`, the `MINIMAL BASH like editing` is appeared. I googled many hours and I tried many solutions, but still my problem is not solved and I can't install grub. also in `live session` or `rescue` mode, I can't use this command(the result is error):

```
chroot /mnt/sysimage
```

Here is some solutions that I tried: many helpful command, `grub-customizer`, `boot-repair` and etc in both `live session` and `rescue` mode. 
I am very tired now, Pls help me and tell an absolute solution to solve this annoying problem, I really need `fedora` these days and I don't want to boot it from `VMware`(and such this) in `windows`, Thank you very much in advance.

***EDIT: *Finally I solved my problem with reinstall fedora with DVD disk(not USB), because always my USB is booted in UEFI mode and I couldn't to change it to legacy mode(for my BIOS)*.

Answer (score 0):

What always worked for me is Rescatux which you can find here: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/

Boot into Rescatux and select Automatic Repair (or worded similar).
If Automatic Repair does not do the trick, select "Restore Grub" and select the Boot Device accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, finally I solved my problem with reinstall fedora with DVD disk(not USB), because always my USB is booted in UEFI mode and I couldn't to change it to legacy mode(for my BIOS).